# Visual Studio 2008 problem on Web.Config synthax highlighter

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-config, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

A strange issue: I've installed the IIS (7.5) Url Rewriter module in order to apply some url rewrite rules to an Asp.Net 3.5 WebForms application.

Recently I've moved these rules in a separate configuration file, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470761/separate-config-file-for-sections-of-web-config) and [here](http://ruslany.net/2010/05/storing-url-rewrite-mappings-in-a-separate-file/).

So in the web.config I've

```
<rewrite>
    <rules configSource="rewriteRules.config" />
</rewrite>
```

All works fine, the project compiles and run with no problems, but the VS xml editor marks the attribute `configSource` as undeclared...

Any idea of why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember  intellisense shipping with either IIS or the module itself, so I'm thinking you are using some external package for schema validation?

If so, it was likely just overlooked when the schema was created.  configSource is a feature of the IIS config model, so its not something you have to implement and as such not something that you'd think to label up when generating an .xsd.

All you need to do is find the .xsd providing the highlighting and add

```
<xs:attribute name="configSource" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
```

at the right level.

**If VS or the module DOES ship with the highlighting,** my apologies for misstating.  To fix that, however, is the exact same solution.  Just find the .xsd that maps the rewrite stuff and add a value for configSource.

Comment: you're right, I've installed this schema: http://ruslany.net/2010/04/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-2-0/ and it doesn't provide configSource attribute for configuration/system.webServer/rewrite/rules element. thanks!